# Menu long-click opens different SearchView widget in action bar

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a search icon in my `Activity`'s action bar and when I click it it opens a default Android `SearchView` widget in my action bar. However, if I long-click capacitive menu button on my Samsung Galaxy S3 device it opens a different `SearchView` widget that doesn't even match with my app's action bar. Furthermore, with menu long-click I can open the `SearchView` widget in my `searchable Activity` that doesn't even have the search icon in the action bar and isn't the desired `Activity` to support the `SearchView` widget in the action bar, it is just for handling the search `Intent`. I'll post some screenshots for you to better understand my problem...

My `MainActivity` with search icon:
[image: My <code>MainActivity</code> with search icon]
My `MainActivity` with `SearchView` widget expanded via search icon press:
[image: My <code>MainActivity</code> with <code>SearchView</code> widget expanded via search icon press]
My `MainActivity` after menu long-click (completely different `SearchView` widget style):
[image: My <code>MainActivity</code> after menu long-click]
My `searchable Activity` (doesn't contain search icon and shouldn't provide search):
[image: My <code>searchable Activity</code>]
My `searchable Activity` after menu long-click (`SearchView` widget shouldn't exist here...):
[image: My <code>searchable Activity</code> after menu long-click]
So I am asking you to help me to find out:

1. Why menu long-click action opens completely different `SearchView` widget?
2. Why is it possible to open that `SearchView` widget in the `searchable Activity` that shouldn't support search functionality but just handle the search `Intent` sent from my `MainActivity` which should be the only `Activity` that contains the search icon and search functionality?
3. How to achieve that menu long-click opens the same `SearchView` widget as the search icon in the action bar and only in the `MainActivity`?
4. If 3 isn't possible then how to completely disable the menu long-click actions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for 4th question.
Add this function in your activity class.

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I guess this would completely disable the search functionality so I can't treat this as an answer.